# Multiple subviews of the same class in Ampersand.js

Tags: javascript, ampersand, ampersand.js

I'm trying to add multiple subviews to my view in Ampersand.js, where the subviews are of the same type. However, Ampersand only seems to allow me to have one object of a class type, and declaring a second overwrites all the attributes of the first. For example:

```
var chart1 = new PieChart('userChart');
var chart2 = new PieChart('deviceChart');

module.exports = PageView.extend({
  pageTitle: 'Home',
  template: require('../../../templates/pages/home.hbs'),
  render: function() {
    this.renderWithTemplate();
    this.renderSubview(chart1, document.getElementById('userChart'));
    this.renderSubview(chart2, document.getElementById('deviceChart'));
  }
});
```

Will only render the second chart, however the first chart will render fine if I comment the second out. Upon inspecting the objects, both have `'deviceChart'` as parameters. I have tried making an entirely new class called `PieChart2` and this removes the problem, but making an entirely new class for every type of chart I may want to show would be ridiculous.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a problem with your PieChart somewhere. I tried to reproduce your problem and everything worked fine and as expected. Here is my working code:

```
var OneView = View.extend({//analogous to your PieChart
  template: '<b></b>',
  props: {
    type: 'string'
  },

  bindings: {
    'type': 'b'
  },
  initialize: function(type){
    this.type = type;
  }
});

var view1 = new OneView('view1');
var view2 = new OneView('view2');

module.exports = View.extend({
  template: '<div><div id="view1"></div><div id="view2"></div></div>',
  autoRender: true,

  render: function(){
    this.renderWithTemplate(this);
    this.renderSubview(view1, document.getElementById('view1'));
    this.renderSubview(view2, document.getElementById('view2'));
    return this;
  }

});
```

By the way, you should instantiate your views inside of the `render` function. Otherwise they'll be the same every time you call `render()` (because of how CommonJS modules work), and most likely it's not what you want. Also, to query elements inside of your view, you can use `this.querySelector('SELECTOR')` instead of `document.getElementById`.